# Code coverage with django debug server

Tags: python, django, coverage.py

I am using coverage.py from http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/ for getting coverage data for my django unittests but I can't seem to figure out how can I run the coverage on the django debug server. I would want to run the django server using:

```
coverage -x manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
```

and when stopping this server, I should get the coverage data using which I can generate the coverage report. But on shutting down the server with CTRL-c, I get

> ^CCoverage.py warning: No data was collected.

I am ready to use any other tool if it is not possible using this coverage.py script.

UPDATE:

With --noreload it does seem to work but I get the following stack trace when generating html coverage report:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/coverage", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('coverage==3.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'coverage')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/coverage/cmdline.py", line 657, in main
    status = CoverageScript().command_line(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/coverage/cmdline.py", line 549, in command_line
    directory=options.directory, **report_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/coverage/control.py", line 599, in html_report
    reporter.report(morfs, config=self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/coverage/html.py", line 83, in report
    self.report_files(self.html_file, morfs, config, config.html_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/coverage/report.py", line 86, in report_files
    report_fn(cu, self.coverage._analyze(cu))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/coverage/html.py", line 198, in html_file
    self.write_html(html_path, html)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/coverage/html.py", line 103, in write_html
    write_encoded(fname, html, 'ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/coverage/backward.py", line 137, in write_encoded
    f.write(text.decode('utf8'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 59130: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, not sure what to make of that.  When I create a brand new Django project, I get some coverage measurement:

```
$ django-admin.py startproject mysite
$ cd mysite
$ coverage run manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.3, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
^C
$ coverage report
Name       Stmts   Miss  Cover
------------------------------
__init__       0      0   100%
manage        11      4    64%
settings      24      0   100%
------------------------------
TOTAL         35      4    89%
```

What OS, Django and coverage versions, etc?  Anything else unusual in your project?

Measuring `runserver` alone may not be what you want, you may only measure the code that watches for file changes and relaunches the server.  A Django test runner with coverage support may suit your needs better.

UPDATE:

Providing the --noreload switch makes coverage measure all your code.

Comment: No there is nothing unusual in my project. The versions that I have are: Ubuntu 10.10, django 1.3, coverage 3.5.

Comment: I see that it is unable to collect data only when include = */views.py set in my .coveragerc. If I remove this line I do get collected data but it shows 0% coverage for the code (My .coveragerc has source = . ). If I remove the source = . setting, I don't see names of files which are present inside the app in my project. The reason I am looking towards collecting data without unittests is that coverage with unit tests tell coverage statistics for tests only which is kind of artificial and does not tell you the coverage in a real life scenario for a certain user interaction.

Comment: I would run it with no include or source directives at all first, to see the full picture of what is getting measured.

Comment: I tried running it without directives also but I see that it does not report coverage statistics of code inside app directories except for __init__ files in each app. Moreover it reports coverage statistics of django modules as well which really clouts report of my project and hence a bit annoying.

Comment: Yes, I'm not suggesting you always run it this way, just trying to figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: Note, the UPDATE: in the answer does solve this problem.  (I missed it on my first read thru)

Comment: @Mark0978: I am not sure what are you suggesting.

Comment: With --noreload it does seem to work but I get the following stack trace when generating html coverage report: